# Displaying X-Axis as DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS.mm on Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In high chart I am plotting two lines.

1st line has data points between , `2018-06-15T04:47:16 and 2018-06-15T04:52:16`
2nd line has data points between ,  `2018-06-15T04:52:16 and 2018-06-15T04:57:16`

Now I do not want them to display the line on that time period. But they are getting extended through out the period , because (probably) Y-Axis does not have Year, hour,minutes and seconds info.

How do I display and evaluate complete date time info in my X-Axis. Hopefully that will help me to show data on interval points and not through out the graph period.
Here is my code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'How to display in DD/MM/YYYY hh:MM:ss'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'In X Axis'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            day: '%e. %b',
            hour:'%H:%M',
            year: '%Y',
            millisecond:'millisecond'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    colors: ['#6CF', '#39F', '#06C', '#036', '#000'],

    // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
    // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
    // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
    series: [{
        name: "Line1",
        data: [
            ["2018-06-15T04:47:16", 8],
       ["2018-06-15T04:52:16", 8]
        ],
        lineWidth:10
    },
    {
        name: "Line2",
        data: [
            ["2018-06-15T04:52:16", 14],
       ["2018-06-15T04:57:16", 8]
        ],
        lineWidth:10
    }
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Highcharts needs time in milliseconds. for datetime axes. So you would have to do `new Date("2018-06-15T04:47:16")` for the different x values.

Comment: I mean, `new Date().getTime()` which returns a millisecond representation of the time.

Comment: @ewolden, I am getting the data back from JSON , won't be able to wrap functions on return data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts needs time in milliseconds for datetime axes.

Based on your comment about not being able to wrap functions on return data, you can do this to get millisecond values for the xAxis:

```
chart: {
  type: 'line',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var series = this.series;

      for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
        let newData = []
        for (let j = 0; j < series[i].data.length; j++) {
          newData.push({x: new Date(series[i].data[j].name).getTime(), y: series[i].data[j].y});
        }
        this.series[i].update({
          data: newData
        }, false);
      }
      this.redraw();
    }
  }
},
```

To always show dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss.mm you need to set the xAxis label to show this, like this:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    format: '{value:%e-%m-%y %H:%M:%S.%L}'
  },
  ...
}
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var series = this.series;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
         let newData = []
          for (let j = 0; j < series[i].data.length; j++) {
            newData.push({x: new Date(series[i].data[j].name).getTime(), y: series[i].data[j].y});
          }
          this.series[i].update({
            data: newData
          }, false);
        }
        this.redraw();
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'How to display in DD/MM/YYYY hh:MM:ss'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'In X Axis'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
      day: '%e. %b',
      hour: '%H:%M',
      year: '%Y',
      millisecond: 'millisecond'
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%e-%m-%y %H:%M:%S.%L}'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Date'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Snow depth (m)'
    },
    min: 0
  },
  colors: ['#6CF', '#39F', '#06C', '#036', '#000'],

  // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
  // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
  // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
  series: [{
      name: "Line1",
      data: [
        ["2018-06-15T04:47:16", 8],
        ["2018-06-15T04:52:16", 8]
      ],
      lineWidth: 10
    },
    {
      name: "Line2",
      data: [
        ["2018-06-15T04:52:16", 14],
        ["2018-06-15T04:57:16", 8]
      ],
      lineWidth: 10
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**JSfiddle working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/j038vrLz/